# How can I make booking schedule in flutter dart atleast after two days from current date?

Tags: flutter, dart

I use an app for booking and here is booking date and time picker code.

Problem is when customer selects date and time it picks date from the same day, I want customers to choose date only after 24 hours. Could anyone help modify this flutter dart code?

Thanks.

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:demandium/components/core_export.dart';

class ScheduleController extends GetxController{

  final ScheduleRepo scheduleRepo;
  ScheduleController({required this.scheduleRepo});

  ///Selected date of day
  DateTime _selectedDate = DateTime.now().add(const Duration(hours: AppConstants.scheduleTime));
  DateTime get selectedData => _selectedDate;


  ///Selected time of day
  // TimeOfDay _selectedTimeOfDay = TimeOfDay(hour: DateTime.now().hour + AppConstants.SCHEDULE_TIME, minute: DateTime.now().minute);
  // TimeOfDay get selectedTimeOfDay => _selectedTimeOfDay;

  String _schedule = '';
  String get schedule => _schedule;

  String? _postId;

  // @override
  // void onInit() {
  //   super.onInit();
  //   // initializeTime();
  //  // _buildSchedule();
  // }



  Future<void> selectDate() async {
    final DateTime? picked = await showDatePicker(
        context: Get.context!,
        initialDate: DateTime.now(),
        firstDate: DateTime.now().subtract(const Duration(days: 0)),
        lastDate: DateTime(2101));
    if (picked != null) {
      _selectedDate = picked;
      update();
      selectTimeOfDay();
    }
  }

  Future<void> selectTimeOfDay() async {
    final TimeOfDay? pickedTime = await showTimePicker(
        context: Get.context!,
        initialTime: TimeOfDay(hour: DateTime.now().hour + AppConstants.scheduleTime, minute: DateTime.now().minute));

    if (pickedTime != null) {
      _selectedDate = DateTime(_selectedDate.year, _selectedDate.month, _selectedDate.day, pickedTime.hour, pickedTime.minute);
      update();

     _buildSchedule();
    }
  }


  Future<void> _buildSchedule() async {
    _schedule = DateConverter.dateToDateAndTime(_selectedDate);

    if(_postId!=null && _schedule.isNotEmpty){
      updatePostInformation(_postId!,_schedule);
    }
    //_schedule = "${DateConverter.dateTimeStringToDateOnly(_selectedDate.toString())} ${_selectedDate.hour.toString().padLeft(2,'0')}:${_selectedDate.minute.toString().padLeft(2,'0')}:00";
    update();
  }

  bool checkScheduleTime(){
    return  _selectedDate.difference(DateTime.now()) > const Duration(hours: AppConstants.scheduleTime, minutes: -15);
  }

  void updateSelectedDate(String? date){
    if(date!=null){
      _selectedDate = DateConverter.dateTimeStringToDate(date);
    }else{
      _selectedDate = DateTime.now().add(const Duration(hours: AppConstants.scheduleTime));
    }
  }
  Future<void> updatePostInformation(String postId,String scheduleTime) async {
    Response response = await scheduleRepo.changePostScheduleTime(postId,scheduleTime);

    if(response.statusCode==200 && response.body['response_code']=="default_update_200"){
      customSnackBar("service_schedule_updated_successfully".tr,isError: false);
    }
  }

  void setPostId(String postId){
    _postId = postId;
  }
}
```

I'm newbie. so looking forward if someone can solve this for me.

Answer (score 0):

Consider adjusting the 'firstDate' variable. Since you've currently set 'firstDate' to begin today, altering it to 24hours later should resolve the issue.

```
firstDate: DateTime.now().subtract(const Duration(days: 0)),
```

->

```
firstDate: DateTime.now().subtract(const Duration(days: 1)),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
final DateTime minDate = DateTime.now().add(const 
Duration(days: 1));
final DateTime? picked = await showDatePicker(
    context: Get.context!,
    initialDate: minDate,
    firstDate: minDate,
    lastDate: DateTime(2101));
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**